# How does one create a title page in LyX?

Tags: lyx, titles

What's the easiest way to create a good-looking title page in LyX?

What I've currently found is a little bit of a hack. It doesn't place the title in the center, and uses raw LaTeX boxes for the `titlepage` environment. In the title page, I used the title envornment (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). In the editor, it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The best way I've found was simply to add things manually. I needed a fairly complex title page for a thesis, and Iv'e found that doing things by hand worked best.

1. Use the titlepage environment as you suggested.
2. Use boxes (Insert->Box->Frameless), and then separate various parts in the box by inserting vertical spaces.
3. Do not set the text to "Title", but rather use the "Plain Layout", and customized text layout to play around with the text size.

This can be done more intelligently using layouts, but for one document, I don't think it's worth the hassle.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, except for 2. Why do you need the box?